# Configuring Azure Redis session cache for ASP.NET MVC 5 web application not possible in web.config

Tags: redis, asp.net-mvc-5, session-state, redis-cache, .net-4.7.2

We want to use the Azure Redis service as a session cache for our MVC 5 web application.
For that we use Nuget **[Microsoft.Web.RedisSeessionStateProvider](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Release-Notes)**, which was updated to v3.0.2 recently.

However, putting that specific version in the web.config throws an error saying that the session state provider must inherit from `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` (namespace System.Web.SessionState).

The RedisSessionStateProvider v3.0.2 from the Nuget inherits from `SessionStateStoreProviderAsyncBase` (namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState), and hence doesn't work.

**The web application is running .NET Framework 4.72! So it must be compatible with v3.x according to the release notes.
The only solution so far is to fall back to version 2.x of the Nuget and use that instead.**

What am I missing?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Were you ever able to find the cause?

Comment: @Anduril no I never found the cause, I ended up removing redis session cache.

Comment: Look here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/five-best-ways-to-use-redis-with-asp-net-mvc/